# Unknown behaviour while comparing two bmp images

Tags: c, algorithm, image-processing

I have two .bmp images, Each have 661 bytes of header. I was skipped header.

After skipping the header, I am trying to compare two images with the following code.
But it is not working.

Is there any logical error In this code, I was tried to figure out what is happening but i was failed.Can any one help me to figure out what is happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    char R,G,B;
} colorRGB;

colorRGB *RGB_buffer1, *RGB_buffer2;

void main() {
    unsigned char tmpBuf1[651],tmpBuf2[651];
    int i=0;
    int nrline;
    FILE *Img1 = fopen("sample.bmp","r");
    FILE *Img2 = fopen("sample2.bmp","r");
    int height = 256;
    int width = 256;

    fread ( tmpBuf1, 1, 651, Img1 );
    fread ( tmpBuf2, 1, 651, Img2 );

    RGB_buffer1 = (colorRGB *) malloc (3 * width * height) ;
    RGB_buffer2 = (colorRGB *) malloc (3 * width * height) ;

    for ( nrline = 0; nrline < height; nrline++ ) {
        fread( RGB_buffer1 + nrline * width, 1, width * 3, Img1 );
        fread( RGB_buffer2 + nrline * width, 1, width * 3, Img2 );
    }
    fclose (Img1);
    fclose (Img2);

    for( i = 0; i < height; i++ )
        if( (RGB_buffer1[i].R != RGB_buffer2[i].R) && 
            (RGB_buffer1[i].G != RGB_buffer2[i].G) && 
            (RGB_buffer1[i].B != RGB_buffer2[i].B)  ) break;
    if ( i == height )
        printf ( "Images are same\n" );
    free (RGB_buffer1);
    free (RGB_buffer2);
}
```

Comment: What exactly you want to ask ?

Comment: Rather than ignore the header, use it to determine the height, width, color depth, pallet, etc.  You do not even know the header size until you examine some of the first bytes.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Comment: Quick check, are the files exactly 197259 bytes in size? Also what is `sizeof(colorRGB)`?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked too closely, but here are a few problems I can spot immediately. First, if any of the color bytes in a pixel is different, you should indicate that the images are different. In other words, change the && (and) operators to || (or) in your for loop:

```
for( i = 0; i < height; i++ )
    if( (RGB_buffer1[i].R != RGB_buffer2[i].R) || 
        (RGB_buffer1[i].G != RGB_buffer2[i].G) || 
        (RGB_buffer1[i].B != RGB_buffer2[i].B)  ) break;
```

Also, you are only examining the first *height* pixels of the images, but there are *height x width* pixels in the bitmap. So the code that checks the bitmaps should be modified to

```
for( i = 0; i < height*weight; i++ )
    if( (RGB_buffer1[i].R != RGB_buffer2[i].R) || 
        (RGB_buffer1[i].G != RGB_buffer2[i].G) || 
        (RGB_buffer1[i].B != RGB_buffer2[i].B)  ) break;
if ( i == height*weight )
    printf ( "Images are same\n" );
```